# PHP uploading 0 bytes image

Tags: php, upload

When I upload an imagen with PHP, I get no errors and the image is 0 bytes on server. 
Things considered:

- File_uploads is On in phpinfo()
- Upload_max_filesize is 8M in phpinfo()
- Upload_tmp_dir is set and has 777 permisions
- If I run file_exists($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']), it returns
  true
- If i run getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']), I get an Read
  Error notice. The image is valid and can be opened with system image
  viewer

I am using a very simple upload script for testing:

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
        Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

//$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/upload';
$uploaddir = '';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

When I submit the file, I get no errors and the image is created in the destination folder, with the correct name and extension, but as the title says, it is 0 bytes (of course, it can't be oppened).

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT** 
*Sajad Karuthedath* just made me see that $_FILE['file']['size'] value is 0 !! What can be the problem causing files are not being uploaded correctly?

**EDIT 2**
Uploading txt, pdf, tar files is working properly.. The problem is only with image type files!

Comment: No errors, because you're not checking for them, or your system's settings are enabled for it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Try `$uploaddir = 'upload/';` if running your script from the root of your server.

Comment: Hi Fred, there are no errors on the logs. Also, trying error_reporting(E_ALL) in the script still does not show anything.
The upload dir is not the issue, since it only sets where the new file is created, and the script is creating the file correctly (with 0 bytes size) on the root or upload folder.

Comment: did you restart your server after changing max upload size ?? @dieguit

Comment: They probably are not getting displayed. Try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also try `$uploadfile = $uploaddir ."/" . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);` but your `$uploaddir = '';` is empty, so that could be a factor.

Comment: That is not the problem. Please read everything I write, i am testing this with an 10kb image.

Comment: I need to know where you are running your script from, the root? If so, your server probably won't let you. Use a sub-folder in your directory variable and set it to 755, not 777.

Comment: Also make sure your tmp folder isn't full, or corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple upload script ,

*you should check for errors before saving to server*

```
 if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
      }
```

**Note:** don't forget to restart your server or xampp after changing phpinfo()

**Note**: also change `post_max_size = 25M` in php

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. File has no error, this a dump of the object:
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => logo_pers.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/tmp/php32ogoT
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 0
        )

Answer (score 0):

In order to track the issue just add an "exit;" straight after the "move_uploaded_file..." command and if the file is properly uploaded it's the code after the "move_upload" which is wrong.
In my case I was opening the uploaded file after upload with an overwrite (w+) option in order to check the lock state of the file. which was making a empty file.